# Jquery Geocomplete. Show users current location on page load

Tags: jquery, google-maps, mobile, geolocation

I'm using **jquery.geocomplete.js** for a mobile site - I want it to load showing the users' current location on the map. The only default location options seem to be a set of fixed co-ordinates or a country name. Is it possible to show how to implement this within the Geolocation code? Here's what I have currently:

```
$(function(){
        var options = {
          map: ".map_canvas",              
          location: [-35.3075, 149.124417],
          mapOptions: {
            zoom: 3
          },
          zoom: 1,
          types: ['establishment'],              
          country: 'au'              
        };

        $("#geocomplete").geocomplete(options).val(); 

    });
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

What you'll need for this, is **to access the geolocation of the navigator object**

```
if(navigator.geolocation){
    /*
     * getCurrentPosition() takes a function as a callback argument
     * The callback takes the position object returned as an argument
     */
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        /**
         * pos will contain the latlng object
         * This must be passed into the setCenter instead of two float values
         */
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);  //
        map.setCenter(pos); //center the map based on users location
    }, function(){
        //client supports navigator object, but does not share their geolocation
    });
}else{
    //client doesn't support the navigator object
}
```

Of course, the above code MUST come after you instantiate the map instance.

You can [read the documentation about Geolocation for Google Maps API here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation).

You can also [see the fullscreen example here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/map-geolocation)

And finally. [here's a jsFiddle implementing this](http://jsfiddle.net/dLrvq/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ohgodwhy. I've added that in after the map code and it now asks for my location, which is great. I'm having trouble applying this code to my map though. I need to somehow integrate it into the "location" line I guess.

**location: (navigator.geolocation),** doesn't seem to work, neither does trying to add it to a function. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks again

Comment: @Desmond the Map *does not* need to have any a `location` passed in when you construct it. You simply need to instantiate the map object by supplying options, until you call `setCenter(pos)`, then the map will load the center, or `setCenter(some_default_pos)` in the event they don't support the navigator

Comment: @Desmond I'll make it easy on you, [here is a jsFiddle showing how to do this](http://jsfiddle.net/dLrvq/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The map is loading using the location based services now. I just need to figure out how to get Geocomplete search to work with it, I will post back here when I do! Thanks again for your time!